# What i need to know to understand augmented reality

Tags: computer-vision, augmented-reality

First off let me say that i can use AR SDK(like artoolkits) to build an AR app. But now i want to know more about how it works(like the detector,tracking...) because it's kind of annoying when you use something but don't understand it(of course it have something to do with my study as well).
So basically lets assume that i want to do AR without using SDK, what knowledge i need to know to do that. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

p/s:sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Don't mind! Many SO members are non native.

Comment: Yeah, you are right.But this project relate to my study as well so i hope someone can give me some hint, at least to know where i should begin to research.Anyway, thanks you menjaraz :D

Comment: You may help people to help you by filling properly your own user profile fields. It's a significant part of the input needed to elaborate proper answer to any question put.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some thoughts which may help you:

### MUST (Wikipedia's entries)

- [Virtual reality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_reality).
- [Augmented reality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_reality) (french version available [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_reality))

They provide links pointing to many relevant references.

### FORUMS (Picked at random)

- [AR Augmented Reality Forum](http://www.augmented-reality-forum.com/index.php)
- [The International Augmented Reality Meetup Groups Forum](http://www.armeetup.org/forum/)
- [Forum La réalité augmentée](http://forum.la-realite-augmentee.fr/) (in french)

To keep up with the state of the art.

### COURSE SYLLABUS (Picked at random)

- [University of Illinois](https://wiki.engr.illinois.edu/display/cs498mar/Course+syllabus)

To have a glimpse of what is actually taught.

### OPENSOURCE PROJECTS (Picked at random)

- [Google code](http://code.google.com/hosting/search?q=label%3aAugmentedReality)
- [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/directory/os%3awindows/?q=AUGMENTED%20REALITY)

To get involved hands-on in down-to-the-metal coding.